# Referencing all of a collection of dependent objects objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, has-one

I have three activerecord classes: Klass, Reservation and Certificate
A Klass can have many reservations, and each reservation may have one Certificate

The definitions are as follows...

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true  
  has_many :certificates, through: :reservations
  attr_accessible :name

  def kill_certs
    begin
      p "In Kill_certs"
      self.certificates.destroy_all
      p "After Destroy"
    rescue Exception => e
      p "In RESCUE!"
      p e.message
    end  
  end

end
```

---

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :klass
  has_one :certificate, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  attr_accessible :klass_id, :name
end
```

---

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

---

I would like to be able to delete/destroy all the certificates for a particular klass within the klass controller with a call to Klass#kill_certs (above)

However, I get an exception with the message:

```
"In RESCUE!"
"Cannot modify association 'Klass#certificates' because the source 
reflection class 'Certificate' is associated to 'Reservation' via :has_one."
```

I('ve also tried changing the reservation class to "has_many :certificates", and then the error is...

```
"In RESCUE!"
"Cannot modify association 'Klass#certificates' because the source reflection
 class 'Certificate' is associated to 'Reservation' via :has_many."
```

It's strange that I can do Klass.first.certificates from the console and the certs from the first class are retrieved, but I can't do Klass.first.certificates.delete_all with out creating an error. Am I missing something?

Is the only way to do this..

```
Klass.first.reservations.each do |res|
  res.certificate.destroy
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens if you call `certificates.each(&:destroy)` instead of `destroy_all` in your `kill_certs` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RoR [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Deleting+from+associations) have clear explanation for this (read bold only for TLDR):

> **Deleting from associations**
>
> What gets deleted?
>
> There is a potential pitfall here: has_and_belongs_to_many and
> has_many :through associations have records in join tables, as well as
> the associated records. So when we call one of these deletion methods,
> what exactly should be deleted?
>
> The answer is that **it is assumed that deletion on an association is
> about removing the link between the owner and the associated
> object(s), rather than necessarily the associated objects themselves.**
> So with has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many :through, the join
> records will be deleted, but the associated records won’t.
>
> This makes sense if you think about it: if you were to call
> post.tags.delete(Tag.find_by(name: 'food')) you would want the ‘food’
> tag to be unlinked from the post, rather than for the tag itself to be
> removed from the database.
>
> However, there are examples where this strategy doesn’t make sense.
> For example, suppose a person has many projects, and each project has
> many tasks. If we deleted one of a person’s tasks, we would probably
> not want the project to be deleted. In this scenario, the delete
> method won’t actually work: **it can only be used if the association on
> the join model is a belongs_to.** In other situations you are expected
> to perform operations directly on either the associated records or the
> :through association.
>
> With a regular has_many there is no distinction between the
> “associated records” and the “link”, so there is only one choice for
> what gets deleted.
>
> **With has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many :through, if you want to
> delete the associated records themselves, you can always do something
> along the lines of person.tasks.each(&:destroy)**.

So you can do this:

```
self.certificates.each(&:destroy)
```

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer, and the link to the docs!